# R: Split intervals in subintervals with equal length and keep information

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame, it contains coordinates and there respective values, these can be at intervals of length 1,2,4,6,8...

```
chr  start end   meth   cov  
chr1 16136 16136 100.00  1.0 
chr1 16137 16138 100.00  4.0
...
chr2 16139 16142 100.00  4.5
chr2 16243 16246 100.00 10.0
chr2 16247 16250  83.33  6.0
...
chr3 16251 16256  50.0   2.0
```

What I want to do is to split each interval (!=1,2) in a equal length of two and keep their respective information, for example:

```
chr1 16136 16136 100.00  1.0    
chr1 16137 16138 100.00  4.0
...
chr1 16139 16140 100.00  4.5
chr1 16141 16142 100.00  4.5
chr1 16243 16244 100.00 10.0
chr1 16245 16246 100.00 10.0
chr1 16247 16248  83.33  6.0
chr1 16249 16250  83.33  6.0
...
chr2 16251 16252  50.0   2.0    
chr2 16253 16254  50.0   2.0
chr2 16255 16256  50.0   2.0
```

I've been thinking in performing a loop (that might not be the most efficient thing), but maybe there is a function already in R that performs it or a more efficient and effective way to.